# Dynamic Chart in Google Sheets Customized by Dual Selection Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, charts, dropdown

I am currently trying to create a dynamic charting system within Google Sheets for a tracker.  Right now, the first chart is how I have it set up, pointing to the sheet "History."  When I select something in the drop-down menu on the Dashboard, it updates the chart to show the values based on the date.

Here is how I want to change it:
I want to create a separate date column that gets updated based on a second drop-down menu.  This second menu would let me select date ranges such as "Last 30 days" or "This year" or "7 days" or whatever custom date ranges I want to configure.  This would make it so the data that gets populated in columns A and B in the History Test tab would be updated based on the 2 selection criteria.  So I could select Value 3 and 7 days or Value 2 and 1 year and the chart would automatically update based on those selections.  I am sure I am over complicating it but hopefully I am just missing a key formula that lets met do this easily.

[Test Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7apbAVyuoD_D42wdshp_d2ytA5gXP2DXCb3-uyOce8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You could try populating the chart range using either `=QUERY()` or `=FILTER()`. Each will require slightly different syntax but the main effort will be to translate/map the options you want to present to the user to the required syntax. E.g. 7 days in `query` could be 'limit 7' (depending on your data structure) and in `filter` it would be '>today()-7'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) to check which interval is set in `D21` (options are `Last 30 days`, `7 days` and `Last year`).
- For each interval, you have to use a slightly different [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en), in this case using [DAYS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296?hl=en).
- The idea is that both the date column and the one corresponding to the value in `B21` are filtered and retrieved by the same formula.
- The value column to retrieve, based on `B21`, is returned with a [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) which uses [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en), [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en) and [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en), as explained, for example, [here](https://davidmeindl.com/google-sheets-formula-to-get-column-by-name-label/).

#### Formula:

```
=IF(Dashboard!D21="Last 30 days",
    FILTER({QUERY(D:F,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Dashboard!B21,D1:F1,0)+3,4),1,"")),C:C},DAYS(TODAY(),C:C)<=30),
 IF(Dashboard!D21="7 days",
    FILTER({QUERY(D:F,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Dashboard!B21,D1:F1,0)+3,4),1,"")),C:C},DAYS(TODAY(),C:C)<=7),
 IF(Dashboard!D21="Last year",
    FILTER({QUERY(D:F,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Dashboard!B21,D1:F1,0)+3,4),1,"")),C:C},DAYS(TODAY(),C:C)<=365))))
```

[image]

Comment: Bingo, that is perfect!  Thank you very much and also thank you for explaining the syntax.  This makes much more sense to me.  I sometimes forget there are multiple ways (or in this case formulas) to skin a cat.